# Style formatting in submit_tag / form tag helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to have the "Save" in bold but not "changes" in the below helper tag.

```
<%= submit_tag "Save changes", :action => "update", :id => @user %>
```

I am unable to put HTML in the string and call html_safe on it, eg "**Save** Changes".html_safe.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string `"Save changes"` gets assigned to the `value` attribute of the `submit` tag created by the `submit_tag` helper method.  You can't put additional html *within* an html tag, which is what you're trying to do here.  If you really want just the first word bolded, then you could consider creating a custom button using HTML and CSS and have it use Javascript to submit the form.  Though you may need to fallback to using a normal submit button if your users don't have Javascript enabled.